# Slide UISlider with the step 0f 1

Tags: ios, swift

I want to make a UISlider with Min value is 0 and Max value is 4 and must be incremented by 1 (Step). Slider should be move One by One (Step) 
**How should i do this?**
**What's the best way to do this?**

Answer (score 4):

This is how i've done it.

1. Add a UISlider to your view in a XIB file or storyboard.
2. In Attributes Inspector of this UISlider, set minimum value to 0 and maximum value to 4.
3. Turn ON Continuous Updates for this UISlider.
4. Create an IBAction in your controller for Value Changed event of this UISlider with the following code (Swift):

   ```
   self.slider.value = round(self.slider.value)
   ```

As users slide their finger on the slider, the control will take incremental steps 0-1-2-3-4.

I hope this is helpful.